# How do I disable my system from going to sleep?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I am getting a web server setup at home on an older AMD 2400+ desktop. I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed and running however, after a time, I can no longer browse to the server. When I go to the keyboard and press a key, everything magically works again.

I have looked through the BIOS and I am not seeing any power saving features enabled. Is there anything like that in Ubuntu? Can it be disabled?

I don't have any GUI installed. This is console only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The right answer for this [located here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25151/4279):

> Have you tried adding the kernel options `acpi=off apm=off` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`?
>
> Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot your computer.

Comment: Whilst adding these options to my grub configuration did stop my machine from going to sleep, it should be noted setting `acpi=off` has a [lot of other effects](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options). The key one for me is that it also disables hyperthreading.

Comment: @PicoutputCls the artice you link states that `acpi=ht` *"Deactivates the ACPI system almost completely; only the components required for hyper threading will be used"*

Comment: The whole system becomes very slow if I set acpi=off

Comment: this setting caused my laptop/ubuntu 20.02 to being restarting at random times. Use with caution.

Comment: On systems with ACPI, ACPI is the preferred way of setting up IRQ routing and initiallizing SMP (multi-CPU / multi-core stuff) during OS boot. If you disable ACPI, chances are, that the APIC's and multiple CPU cores can start up via the older (pre-ACPI) MPS BIOS services, if these are present in the BIOS and in good shape. Otherwise, disabling ACPI may constrain your system to a single CPU core and just the ~15 legacy IRQ's, which will be massively shared by the myriad devices in a modern PC system. I.e. acpi=off can indeed result in a slow or non-booting system.

Answer (score 157):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I successfully used the following to disable suspend:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

And this to re-enable it:

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

From `man systemctl`:

```
mask NAME...  
           Mask one or more units, as specified on the command line. This
           will link these unit files to /dev/null, making it impossible to
           start them. This is a stronger version of disable, since it
           prohibits all kinds of activation of the unit, including
           enablement and manual activation. Use this option with care. This
           honors the --runtime option to only mask temporarily until the
           next reboot of the system. The --now option may be used to ensure
           that the units are also stopped. This command expects valid unit
           names only, it does not accept unit file paths.

 unmask NAME...
           Unmask one or more unit files, as specified on the command line.
           This will undo the effect of mask. This command expects valid
           unit names only, it does not accept unit file paths.
```

Comment: How would I test whether these are or aren't masked already? (And what does `mask` or `unmask` do anyways? Never heard of those before.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare From `man systemctl` "Mask one or more units, as specified on the command line. This will link these unit files to /dev/null, making it impossible to start them. This is a stronger version of disable, since it prohibits all kinds of activation of the unit, including enablement and manual activation. Use this option with care. This honors the --runtime option to only mask temporarily until the next reboot of the system. The --now option may be used to ensure that the units are also stopped. This command expects valid unit names only, it does not accept unit file paths."

Comment: @Centimane - Thanks. So how would I actually check if they already were `mask`ed or not? Obviously I could try just running them and see what happens, but that would potentially cause the side effect of putting my computer to sleep (which would be... bad... it has issues waking up, which is why I want to just ensure it never sleeps.)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare you could just check `/etc/systemd/system/` for a link to `/dev/null`

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare or `systemctl show -p FragmentPath [service]`. The `FragmentPath` property tells you where `systemd` thinks the unit file lives. A masked service will say `/dev/null`

Comment: This worked for me, but had the side effect of bringing the CPU to 70-100% indefinitely whenever I closed the lid, because the system service `systemd-logind` was trying to execute the suspend service but couldn't. The solution is to ignore the lid with `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

Comment: Any way to do this without root privileges?

Comment: Really sorry to revive this ancient thread, just to comment on the suggested solution. If you mask out hibernation, you will not be able to put the system into hibernation manually either. I.e. select it from the start menu etc. This is a real downside. Power management settings don't always appear to work - my dell laptop seems to go into hibernation whenever it feels like it, and to h*ll with any power management settings.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Does the mask [service] persist across reboots, or must this be remasked after a reboot?

Comment: 'sudo systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target'

explicity lists the `target`s (suspend, etc) as `masked`

Comment: @Djizeus's comment in underrated. In my case `systemd-logind` spammed my `/var/log/auth.log` until it filled the disk. **MASKING IS NOT THE WAY TO GO!**

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 38):

**GUI**

Have you looked at:

System -> Preferences -> Power Management

On AC Power Tab, Put computer to sleep when inactive for: "Never"

**Terminal**

Can you open up "gconf-editor"?

Look in: `/apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout`

Try setting `sleep_computer_ac` to `0`

I'm not positive if anything else needs to be changed as well.

Comment: How do I do that on the console? I don't have a gui installed.

Comment: @Mike Wills Updated since you have no gui

Comment: Again, I don't have gnome or any of that installed. It is a pure console.

Comment: Up to date command-line way is: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout '0' && gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout '0'`

Comment: @dess very helpful.  Thanks!  You should post your response in an answer for others to see.

Comment: Note that on Xubuntu you must drag the slider to the far *left* (which is counter-intuitive), to get to the "never" option. Dragging to the right maxes out at a max delay time for suspend of 5 hrs 50 min, so drag far left to get "never."

Comment: @dess , is this permanent or until session ends?

Comment: @ed22 , it's [GSettings](https://developer.gnome.org/GSettings/), so it's permanent in common case.

Comment: I went to Settings -> Power -> Automatic Suspend -> Off and I can now ssh into my desktop after locking the screen.

Comment: How is this upvoted? This does not answer the question for someone who has no GUI. @MikeWills stated clearly - several times - that there is NO GUI INSTALLED. That means there is no `gsettings`. There is no `/apps/gnome-power-manager`. Because gnome is not installed.

Comment: @klugerama the one that I marked as the answer likely worked. But that was my frustration at the time.

Comment: Its doesnt worked, i disabled sleep, but after inactivity 3-4 or more hours, computer did sleep.

Answer (score 19):

None of these described solutions worked for me. The laptop was still going to sleep. Using the Grub Linux command line option of acpi=off caused the laptop to fail to boot. I finally found this solution.

```
sudo vi /etc/default/acpi-support # and then set SUSPEND_METHODS="none"
sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart
```

Based on the original solution from Stephan here: [Keep Ubuntu Server running on a laptop with the lid closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141866/keep-ubuntu-server-running-on-a-laptop-with-the-lid-closed)

Comment: I'm aware that I'm commenting on a posting that is 5 years old by now. With that disclaimer over, please note that the acpi-support package has been deprecated for a while and is now gone. In my particular system, I still have acpid. If you want to see what acpid has to say, try setting OPTIONS="-d -l" (that's a lowercase L) in /etc/default/acpid to produce some output in the syslog i.e. /var/log/daemon log or some such.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the systemctl mask/unmask options, I also use the following to turn suspend on/off for the Gnome desktop.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
```

or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
```

I found these by exploring the settings revealed by the commands listed in [How to dump ALL dconf/gsettings so that I can compare them between two different machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522833/how-to-dump-all-dconf-gsettings-so-that-i-can-compare-them-between-two-different)

Comment: I also had to do both mask, and set sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing', with timeout 0.

Answer (score 8):

Please try looking into these links - [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-disable-screen-blanking-screen-going-blank.html) and [Arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=33497)

This is an excerpt from the [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-disable-screen-blanking-screen-going-blank.html) link:

> By default, the Linux kernel will use
>   screen-save option to disable it you
>   need to **type this command** (it
>   turns off monitor VESA powersaving
>   features):
>
> ```
> $ setterm -powersave off -blank 0
> ```
>
> **If it dumps back you with an error** that read as follows: cannot (un)set
>   powersave mode
>
> You need to shutdown X window system
>   and rerun the above command. Better,
>   **add following two commands to your ~/.xinitrc file:**
>
> ```
> setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
> xset s off
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to note my problems with the accepted answer and provide an alternative solution:

Masking `sleep.target`, `suspend.target` etc. using `systemctl` does do the job, but know that **`systemd-logind` will still try to call** `sleep.target` (or which ever)!

@Djizeus reports that this resulted in an indefinite CPU usage of 70-100% after closing the lid. Personally I experienced `systemd-logind` spamming my `/var/log/auth.log` **until it filled the disk** (tens and tens of lines per second reporting `sleep` is masked).

Taken again from @Djizeus' comment: "[t]he solution is to ignore the lid with `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`".

Comment: I second that. And, as I'm prevented from posting here (being a noob), here goes my counter-suggestion:
edit /etc/systemd/sleep.conf ; 
AllowSuspend=no , 
AllowHibernation=no . See also man systemd-sleep ,
man systemd-sleep.conf .

Answer (score 0):

I found Light Locker, as I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 with LXDE (Lubuntu) Desktop; if you have this desktop you can change the default and manage the monitor through that.  Otherwise you might have to install gconf-editor through terminal if you don't have it.  Light Locker is in can be found in Preferences in the main menu.

Comment: gconf-editor requires a gui.