# Keep Ubuntu Server running on a laptop with the lid closed?

Tags: power-management

I decided to use my Eee PC 1001HA as a home server. I have it connected through Wi-Fi to the router, running Ubuntu Server 12.04. Everything works fine except this annoying problem:

when I close the lid, the ssh server stops working and, I guess, wlan0 too.

Tried the BIOS and nothing, no option about the lid. My wlan0 is a RaLink RT3090.

Tried `ls -lrt /var/log` between lid derivatives, but I can't understand those satanic logs. I can share them if needed.

`pm-powersave.log` seems to be updated between lid movements. So I guess I've to disable this "powersave" service. Can I do this? I don't mind if the server runs all day.

Remember that there is no UI, this is a netbook with a lid and its connected to the ac adapter.

**edit:** This is just a *workaround* but I am able to click the power-button and close the lid quickly. This way the server boots normally and connects to the wireless network automatically. (found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11966677&posted=1#post11966677))

Comment: Try: `sudo nano /etc/default/acpi-support`

Comment: The answers at this location helped me

 - http://askubuntu.com/questions/360615/ubuntu-server-13-10-now-goes-to-sleep-when-closing-laptop-lid

Comment: See also [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid).

Answer (score 157):

To disable entering the sleep mode I had to edit the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file and modify the line:

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

to

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Additionally, ensure that the file also has this line:

```
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
```

Then restart the OS via:

```
sudo service systemd-logind restart
```

Comment: sudo sh -c 'echo "HandleLidSwitch=ignore" >> /etc/systemd/logind.conf' && reboot

Comment: Worked for me on 14.04 x64 server (Lenovo ThinkPad T410)

Comment: Worked for me on 15.10 x64 server (Asus G73JW)

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu Mate 14.04.3 x64 (LTS), running on a Asus K52F. Thanks! (and +1 ;) )

Comment: This worked good for my 14.04

Comment: Worked for me on 16.06 (Lenovo Thinkpad P50)

Comment: I done that like this. And after all i have to reboot. I don't try killl -HUP because i forgot :) and i don't have service systemd-logind restart command.
/etc/systemd/logind.conf


HandleSuspendKey=ignore


HandleHibernateKey=ignore


HandleLidSwitch=ignore

HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore

Comment: meybe 
systemctl restart systemd-logind  ?? on Ubuntu 16.4 LTS

Comment: `HandleLidSwitch=lock` If you want the extra security

Comment: What if I want the display to turn off?

Comment: This worked for me in 18.04

Comment: This worked for me in 20.04

Comment: FYI `sudo service systemd-logind restart` kills the current session. I had to reboot

Comment: it worked for me on ubuntu server 22

Answer (score 18):

**Turn off laptop screen when closed**

This works for me on a new install of Ubuntu Server LTS 18.04.1.

The answer from @user386160 worked great to prevent my laptop from going to sleep.  But I found out that my monitor was staying on even when the lid was closed (a.k.a. generating unnecessary heat).

Here's the additional steps I took to turn off the laptop monitor when the screen was closed:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi-support vbetool
sudo echo "event=button/lid.*" > /etc/acpi/events/lid-button
sudo echo "action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh" >> /etc/acpi/events/lid-button
sudo touch /etc/acpi/lid.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/lid.sh
sudo nano /etc/acpi/lid.sh
```

Then set the contents of the `lid.sh` file to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -q close /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state

if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    sleep 0.2 && vbetool dpms off
fi

grep -q open /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state

if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    vbetool dpms on
fi
```

Comment: Should be top answer, who wants the screen on with the lid closed?

Comment: Didn't work for me on Lenovo ideapad 100, Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: `sudo echo ... > ...` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 11):

just to confirm, 14.04 LTS Server user here on a Dell X100e.

```
sudo apt-get install acpi-support
sudo vi /etc/default/acpi-support # and then set SUSPEND_METHODS="none"
sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart
```

Instantly able to close lid, no issues.

Just posting to confirm the previous posters' solution as the only fix needed. No need (currently) to do anything else in addition to this.

Comment: This did not work for me on server 14.04 LTS. After applying these changes, when I close the lid, the disk drive runs for a second and then wifi goes out.

Comment: This did nothing for me on my Asus G73JW, Ubuntu server 15 , HandleLidSwitch did

Answer (score 6):

Everything stops working because...the laptop goes to sleep! (suspend mode).

To stop, just disable the ACPI *lid-button* event.

Edit `/etc/acpi/event/lidbtn` and comment out the bottom two lines:

```
  # /etc/acpi/events/lidbtn
  # Called when the user closes or opens the lid
  event=button[ /]lid  # comment this out with a # at the beginning
  action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh # same here
```

Reboot, and that should be it.

Comment: Hi izx, I dont have that file. My "/etc/acpi/" has one file "powerbtn". And the "/etc/acpi/events" has another file with same name: "powerbtn"

Answer (score 5):

I am using 14.04 LTS with ASUS EEE.

The solution by Stephan above didn't work for me.  However, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/361087/59774) worked.

Comment: I.e., editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`. This also [worked for me on a non-Ubuntu system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52645/4319), with a special needed for the behavior of the DE started by the DM.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach,

for me on Ubuntu Server 20.10, changing logind.conf did not help (although I've also done that, haven't tested this solution without those changes in that file), and the

> sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target
> hybrid-sleep.target

-approach caused systemd to consume 100% of my CPU, but from this manpage
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/systemd-sleep.conf.5.html
I managed to get it to work (no reboot or anything) by disabling sleep in it's entirety;
In /etc/systemd/sleep.conf add the following lines

```
AllowSuspend=no
AllowHibernation=no
AllowSuspendThenHibernate=no
AllowHybridSleep=no
```

Although that might not be an option if you want to be able to suspend it etc. in some other situation, but at least it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This worked for me on a laptop running Ubuntu Server 22.04. I was glad to see the screen still turns off as I close the lid, so I didn't have to worry about those extra steps in the other answer above.

Comment: I couldn't edit my above comment, but I wanted to mention a similar option I saw in described in `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`. Instead of modifying the `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` directly, you can add a file to `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf.d/` (I had to create the dir first). Files in there take precedence over `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`. So I created `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf.d/00-sleep.conf` and put exactly these lines in it.

```[Sleep]
AllowSuspend=no
AllowHibernation=no
AllowSuspendThenHibernate=no
AllowHybridSleep=no```

Comment: For me on server 20.04 w/ Dell laptop the screen stays on when closed unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

Editing the /etc/systemd/logind.conf helped, but not with only adding

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

I also had to add the lines:

```
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

and

```
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
```

Answer (score 3):

I think setting the `SUSPEND_METHODS="none"` option in `/etc/default/acpi-support`, does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me - my Ubuntu Server install didn't have /etc/acpi/event/lidbtn either, but I installed the acpi-support package and then it showed up.

The package installs a whole bunch of other X11 related packages but doesn't enable graphical mode, don't worry.

Once I commented the last two lines as above then my laptop stayed running with the lid closed.

Answer (score 0):

Approach that worked for me running Ubuntu Server 22.04 on a MacBook Pro 7,1; edit the login.conf file and utilize setterm cli command. This also helped make sure my screen and logo backlight turned off.

Edit file: /etc/systemd/logind.conf
Adjust these two parameters:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
```

Also, in the terminal, type:
`setterm --blank 1 --powerdown 2`

Comment: got this error `setterm: terminal xterm-256color does not support --blank`