# how to keep ubuntu on and unlocked while closing the laptop lid?

Tags: 12.10, laptop, suspend, lid, teamviewer

I want to close the laptop lid but not even lock the screen!

I generally use TeamViewer from my phone and thus I need my Laptop to stay on all the time.

Though a locked screen can be unlocked but i dont want it to happen by default unless I mannually do it!

Also It should not suspend itself at all!

How can I get this done..

I refered this - [Keep Ubuntu Server running on a laptop with the lid closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141866/keep-ubuntu-server-running-on-a-laptop-with-the-lid-closed)

but it does not exactly answer my question.

Comment: The answers at this location helped me

 - http://askubuntu.com/questions/360615/ubuntu-server-13-10-now-goes-to-sleep-when-closing-laptop-lid

Comment: Did you solve this? I also I guess, you don't have a touchscreen otherwise you would have wanted to [disable the touchscreen on closing laptop lid](https://askubuntu.com/q/525878), do you?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System Setting` -> `Brightness and Lock` and turn *Lock* off, turn the time delay of lock to *Never* just to be sure.

Comment: okay the suspention has stoped and screen is not locked now...I can see the desktop on the teamviewr on the fone but it does not function when the lid is closed...i can only see...and i checked it out and realised that the funcns i do here are done there(like alt+tab) but not reflected on my screen on the fone...why so?

Comment: Is the screen dim settings on maybe?

Comment: nope....its off

Comment: No idea then... Sorry. :/