# Ubuntu Server 13.10 now goes to sleep when closing laptop lid

Tags: server, laptop, power-management, 13.10

I recently upgraded to the latest version (13.10).  I have it running on an old laptop.  Since the upgrade, whenever I close the laptop lid, it goes to sleep mode.

Any idea on how to fix?

I've tried the solution here:

[Keep Ubuntu Server running on a laptop with the lid closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141866/keep-ubuntu-server-running-on-a-laptop-with-the-lid-closed)

After installing acpi-support I don't have the file: /etc/acpi/event/lidbtn to edit.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: after i read your question, i checked my system settings. in ubuntu 13.04 in system settings - power i had chosen 'when lid is closed do nothing' but now, after the upgrade to 13.10 it is changed in 'when lid is closed suspend'. so i think you have to change it manually.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I've had the same problem and after a lot of reading, I realized that Ubuntu 13.10 uses `systemd-logind` and it handles the lid close event. To disable entering the sleep mode edit the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file and uncomment/modify/add the line:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Then execute `sudo restart systemd-logind` or simply reboot.

This has solved the problem on my PC.

## Update for 15.04

I'm not sure if Ubuntu 15.04 already switched to `systemd` completely. If so, the new command for restarting the service is `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`.

Comment: I get `Unknown job: systemd-logind`...

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: switching this line to `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate` brought back the 13.04 functionality

Comment: The "execute" bit isn't `sudo restart systemd-logind`, it's `sudo service  systemd-logind restart`. Other than that, works like a charm :)

Comment: @daniel - it still works with `sudo restart systemd-logind` on my 14.04.2 LTS. It is registered as an upstart service in `/etc/init/systemd-logind.conf`. I believe Ubuntu is configured to execute the same command after `sudo service systemd-logind restart` for compatibility reasons - it should be described in the `man service` page.

Comment: @jeremija Using 14.10 beta here; either it's broken in it, or they changed it. Sorry, should've thought of that :)

Comment: No longer working in 15.10 either. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Works in 16.04 daily build as of today. Thanks! - This is now the third place (after gnome and gdm) where I have to disable suspend. But I'm still not sure that no clever application will suspend my "serverlaptop" at some point. Is there any kernel or systemctl or /proc option to forbid suspend from ANY application?

Comment: Works well in Ubuntu server 16.04.1 LTS. `sudo service systemd-logind restart` worked for me.

Comment: confirming it also worked for Ubuntu server 22.04 with Asus notebook. Lid is closed and the server is accessible by ssh.