# How do I configure laptop lid closing event to turn off screen but not put computer to sleep?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, laptop

I just upgraded to **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** and figured out that there is no option in settings to *change the lid closing behavior*.

I tried the command line method from the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360615/ubuntu-server-13-10-now-goes-to-sleep-when-closing-laptop-lid):

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

worked successfully. But, this thing doesn't turn off the screen like it happens in Windows.

I want to keep the System running, but turn the screen off when the lid is closed.

Comment: you might need to look in two places, settings -> power AND settings -> display

Answer (score 2):

`HandleLidSwitch=ignore` does just that: it ignores lid behavior.  So the screen will not turn off if you use this method.

---

The following answer is adapted from [this source](https://mensfeld.pl/2018/08/ubuntu-18-04-disable-screen-on-lid-close/)

You will need to write a script:

In a terminal, create the file `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`, make it executable, and instruct your system to reference this file for the behavior of lid "events":

```
sudo touch /etc/acpi/lid.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/lid.sh
sudo echo 'event=button/lid.*' | tee --append /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
sudo echo 'action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh' | tee --append /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
```

then, open the script for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/acpi/lid.sh
```

The contents of this file should be: (replace `your_username` with your username)

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=your_username
grep -q close /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
  su -c  "sleep 1 && xset -display :0.0 dpms force off" - $USER
fi
grep -q open /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
  su -c  "xset -display :0 dpms force on &> /tmp/screen.lid" - $USER
fi
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to save and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Reboot your system.

This may not work with multiple users.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.10 /etc/acpi and /etc/acpi/events do not exist. If I create them myself, should this work or it is moved somewhere else? Thanks.

Comment: @conualfy you should install the acpi daemon to listen the events first. `sudo apt install acpid`