# Ubuntu 19.10 - Laptop won't reboot/shutdown if the lid is closed (SSH)

Tags: ssh, power-management, laptop, reboot, acpi

I'm using an HP laptop as a server, so the lid is almost always closed and it is the only display "plugged". I have configured Ubuntu to "do nothing" if the lid is closed and AC is plugged and this works just fine. However, if I remote in via SSH and trigger a reboot then the system does not reboot properly.

It's as if the laptop goes to sleep instead: if I open the lid with a narrow-angle I can see the Power button blinking as if the laptop was sleeping. If I completely open the lid the laptop display lights up and the laptop starts the reboot process normally.

I would like to be able to reboot normally via SSH, without having to manually open the lid.

Can't think of a reason to justify this, is it may be the Nvidia discrete GPU?

Comment: This a BIOS issue. It doesn't start the OS if the lid is closed. Unles there is an option in BIOS, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Is it? Basically it's as if I send the request to reboot or power-off to Ubuntu but it won't do it as long as the lid is closed. As soon as I open the lid the desktop appears with the icons etc- for a second and then the PC reboots.

Comment: Ubuntu does reboot. But the process includes giving the control to BIOS.

Comment: Ubuntu does not reboot. I open the lid, see the desktop, then Ubuntu starts the reboot.
Solved by `sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and uncommented `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`

Answer (score 2):

https://askubuntu.com/a/361087/1042108

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

uncomment (remove `#`) `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`
and then `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`