# Disable touchscreen on closing laptop lid

Tags: touchscreen, lid

I configured my laptop so the display screen stays on and unlocked when I close the lid, because I want to do sleep and lock manually when I need it to.

This works fine so far with only one drawback, because I have a touchscreen:

When the touchscreen lid is closed and I carry it around into the next room the keyboard-keys touch automatically on random points on the screen, And when I open the lid, lots of *funny things* happened ;)

At the moment I use a **workaround** with the `dconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Open dconf-editor and navigate to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` and set `lid-close-ac-action` and `lid-close-battery-action` there to "blank" or "suspend":

[image]

But this is not perfect because it also **locks the screen**, I would like to keep the screen unlocked but still disable the touchscreen while the lid is closed.

So How can I disable touch when the lid is closing and enable it when opening?
How can I configure this?

*I use a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro*

---

**possible attempt:** I know of a bug, that the touchscreen gets disabled if I turn on the power save option of my touchscreen. I could put this in two scripts that are called when there is a  [Catch lid close and open events](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525995/catch-lid-close-and-open-events) and another script that disables power save when opening the lid

Comment: Are you able to disable your touchscreen using `dconf-tool`. I don't have touchscreen laptop,but I think there is settings for touch screen in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals`.

Comment: there is only `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen` which should control, if you may turn the screen, but rotation doesn't work anyway in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Does disabling `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen` disables yours laptop touchscreen.

Comment: I didn't try, cause it sais, it would prevent rotation, which is not what I want.