# Ubuntu graphics performance slow with external monitor AND notebook lid closed

Tags: nvidia, performance, external-monitor, nouveau

Notebook Asus N56VJ, Ubuntu 16.04, nouveau driver.

I intend to use external monitor with notebook lid closed.
But in such a configuration, it appears that the graphics performance is low as compared to when the lid is not closed. The behavior is not affected if the external monitor setup is mirror/extended.

This looks strange that on one working external monitor , the performance is low. This evident, by the mouse cursor movement looks jumpy and not at all smooth. As soon as i open the lid, the performance is back to normal.

The proprietary NVIDIA driver is available for my notebook, but it is just unusable, for multi-monitor setup, it does not even work.

Secondly, another minor issue is that when i disconnect the external monitor, the correct behaviour should be that all the windows/applications running on external monitor should get back to the  primary display, but this does not happen on the disconnect trigger event, but if i do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and then agian <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, the apps come back to primary display as expected. Though i can live without this minor issue, but a fix would be handy.

Any help is appreciated, or if i can give more debug logs etc, please let me know what and how,in the comments.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: no, havent found yet.

Comment: I tried the solution suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141866/keep-ubuntu-server-running-on-a-laptop-with-the-lid-closed) and it worked for me.