# CPU useage spikes when I unplug external monitor

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, cpu, external-monitor, systemd-logind

I am dual booting ubuntu 20.04 desktop on my mid 2012 macbook pro. I'd like to run it as headless server with the lid closed. To try to do this I set systemctl default to multi-user, disabled gdm, and set grub to boot into single user mode. Everything is working fine (~2% CPU) when I have an external monitor plugged in but as soon as I unplug the external monitor cpu usage spikes (~40%), and systemd_logind starts running reportedly using ~80% cpu. When I plug the external monitor back in systemd_logind stops using a bunch of cpu and the system goes back to around 2% cpu.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I tried to install ubuntu server originally, but it wouldn't let me do the partitioning the way I needed to dual boot, so i had to use desktop to install.

Comment: "and set grub to boot into single user mode" - I don't understand the reasoning behind this if you intend to use it as a server, but could you explain how exactly you did it?

Comment: I might be mistaken when i said I set grub into single user mode. What I did is followed the instructions here. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/boot-ubuntu-20-04-command-console/

Comment: I'm not sure what the kernel parameters do, but I'm quite sure you don't need them for what you want to achieve. Try undoing the changes to `/etc/default/grub`. All you need to do is setting systemd's default target to multi-user.

Comment: I actually tried with just multi-user, before trying the grub changes. Same behavior unfortunately.

Comment: Does `journalctl` show any relevant logs for the time range when the display is not connected? Run `journalctl -f`, disconnect the display, wait a couple of seconds and reconnect it. BTW, what happens when the lid is open?

Comment: Running `journalctl -f` and unplugging got me:  
 systemd-logind[772]: Suspending...  
 systemd-logind[772]: Unit suspend.target is masked, refusing operation.  
 systemd-logind[772]: Failed to execute suspend operation: Permission denied  

So I googled a bit and found this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1180519/1132566  
Which seemed to fix the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep Ubuntu Server running on a laptop with the lid closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141866/keep-ubuntu-server-running-on-a-laptop-with-the-lid-closed)

Comment: Yep, specifically this response form that https://askubuntu.com/a/1180519/1132566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow suggestions from @denzel to run `journalctl -f` while unplugging got me:

> systemd-logind[772]: Suspending...
> systemd-logind[772]: Unit suspend.target is masked, refusing operation.
> systemd-logind[772]: Failed to execute suspend operation: Permission denied

So I googled a bit and found this answer askubuntu.com/a/1180519/1132566 Which seemed to fix the issue.