# Laptop Lid Behaviour

Tags: lid

I want my laptop running Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS to not shut off when closing the lid. All the answers I've found involve the GUI which I do not have. Is there a command to change this?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/594417/1222991)? It should do exactly what you’re looking for 

Comment: @matigo Didnt work :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep Ubuntu Server running on a laptop with the lid closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141866/keep-ubuntu-server-running-on-a-laptop-with-the-lid-closed)

Comment: @vanadium nope :(