# How to dump ALL dconf/gsettings so that I can compare them between two different machines?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, wine, dconf

#### The problem:

I have two machines, both with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 up-to-date, and both with installed the latest CrossOver Linux(1) to run MS Office 2007 on it. I know, it's a proprietary program, but the problem is more general and affect Wine too. Please do not stop reading.

Both machines have a spanish keyboard working well most of the time (showing sometime a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272) but I think it's unrelated). The problem is that on one of them there is a set of program running under Crossover Wine affected by a [bug that makes the dead keys not working](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=20133) on some program, notably MS Office Word (there is also [another bug for another issue but it seems it is the same  problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1278569)).

Disabling IBus in Language Support -> Change Keyboard input method and unsetting `XMODIFIERS` works on one machine but not on the other (!).

So it must be some strange setting doing the difference...

#### The question

Is it possible to dump all the gsetting/dconf/whatever configuration database(2) in a readable file so that I can check differences with `diff -u`?

I know that

```
gsettings list-recursively org.freedesktop.ibus.general
```

works, but I am quite puzzled that

```
gsettings list-recursively org.freedesktop
```

gives the error

```
No such schema 'org.freedesktop'
```

...so it seems that I can't dump all of the registry in one go. Any hint?

---

*Footnotes*:

(1) This is a version of Wine with added technical support and fixes to run some program better. A lot of the improvement percolates on free Wine, so I think is a good part of the Ubuntu ecosystem; nevertheless I do not add the link to avoid being accused of publicity `;-)`

(2) Can we call it what it really is --- a *registry* like the infamous windows one?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199836/49853

Comment: As of Ubuntu MATE 20.04 `gsettings list-recursively | sort | grep org.freedesktop` works well

Comment: @geekQ `gsettings list-recursively` also works already in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Have you found the difference between the systems at the end?

Comment: @Mitar sorry, I don't remember... :-(

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the `dump` command of `dconf` (https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-tool.html):

```
dconf dump /
```

As always you can use output redirection to save the output to a file for later use:

```
dconf dump / > dconf-backup.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

`gsettings list-recursively` needs a full schema name, it doens't work with partial schema names. So You can't use `org.freedesktop`.

But you can do this with `dconf`:

```
 dconf dump /org/freedesktop/
```

Note the different notation here: `dconf` doesn't use schemas but directories.

Comment: As of Ubuntu MATE 20.04 `gsettings list-recursively` SCHEMA is optional, when not given - *all* the settings are dumped.

Comment: @geekQ It is optional in Ubuntu 18.04 too, at least for the main (Gnome) flavor.