# How to sort files order by "type" for all directories?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I'm asking about sorting my files ordered by "type" for all directories ?

I could sort it for one directory but I couldn't find any solutions for my req (if possible) .

Comment: You mean within the file explorer - Nautilus?

Comment: @pa4080 yes, not in terminal list files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could change `Nautilus` preferences: `Nautilus menu > Preferences > View (tab)` and set `Arrange items: By Type`.

[image]

---

Or you can use `dconf-editor`. First install it:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then launch the application `dconf-editor` and go to `org > gnome > nautilus > preferences` and change the *Default sort order*.

[image]

---

Another way is to use `gsettings` to `set` this value:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order 'type'
```

References:

- [How can I script the settings made by gnome-tweak-tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971067/how-can-i-script-the-settings-made-by-gnome-tweak-tool)