# 18.04: re-enable preferred keystroke combination for Workspaces?

Tags: workspaces

How do I invoke Workspaces on Ubuntu 18.04?  It used to be:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt+</kbd> (<kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd>)

But my laptop crashed. After rebooting, those key combinations don't do anything.

Is there a way to configure Ubuntu to make them work again?

Comment: Can you check what do you have here "System Settings..." > "Keyboard" then switch to "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab?

Comment: Thank you so much.  It was reset to the default (?) which was "Super+Page Down" and "Super+Page Up".  I configured back to what I'm used too.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workspaces is set in Tweaks.

If you have Tweaks installed, go to Workspaces and set the number of Workspaces required there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to save out the preferences, so if it crash again, I can just restore my preferences?

Comment: It's not recent but you could try the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/522843/307670