# Dolphin behaves differently on two laptops with the same software

Tags: dolphin, previews

I have two laptops sitting side by side, one from HP and the other from Dell.  Both are running Kubuntu 22.04 with Plasma 5.24.7, KDE Frameworks 5.92.0, QT 5.15.3, kernel 5.15.0.53-generic (64 bit), and X11. Both are running Dolphin 21.12.3. Both have **kio-extras** installed.

Yet there is a painful difference in how the two laptops display a folder of JPEGs.  In each case the Dolphin settings under General/Previews have "JPEG Images" checked.
On the Dell, the items in the folder are preview images, just as they should be, but on the HP they are just icons... not what I want at all.

What could account for the difference?

*Update 1:* There are two questions in the previews configuration page.

"Skip previews for local files above". I accepted the default: No limit.

"Skip previews for remote files above." I accepted the default: No previews.  But this is a badly worded question.  Does "No previews" mean "Don't skip any" or "Skip all of them"?

Comment: Are you sure they both have the same settings; ie. you may have one set for "*Use common display style for all folders*", but the other is using "*Remember display style for each folder*"? and you're display a directory where you've saved a different default view etc.   [Please note: how it shows in settings may differ on your box to the messages I've taken from my own; I'm not on *jammy* and have a newer `dolphin` on my release]

Comment: Guiverc gave me an idea about differing configs. Then I thought how nice it would be to use `diff` for the comparison. Then I found this: https://askubuntu.com/q/522833/1157519 Yes, I am aware that this is for Gnome and that you are on KDE. I don't know what is the equivalent tool/workflow on KDE to dump/export configs into text files, or even, if it's possible; but I would try to look in this direction.

Comment: One more idea: Thumbnailers often have a setting for file size treshold: "Generate thumbnails for only files that are smaller than X MB." Maybe on the problematic machine this treshold is set very low? And one more: the "preview images" are often referred to as "thumbnails". I would look in configs for the string "thumb".

Comment: The Dell version my be running the OEM version of Kubuntu...

Comment: You say "The Dell version my be running the OEM version of Kubuntu".  I don't remember where I downloaded my Kubuntus from, but if this was the problem, wouldn't it show up in the version numbers?