# Ubuntu 16.04 + unplug VGA => sleep

Tags: 16.04, suspend, vga

I just installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 on a little notebook (acer aspire). I will use it as a little linux server.
As my screen is dead, I needed to plug an external display with VGA. Everything works fine, but, when I remove the cable, the computer instantaneously go to sleep.

I tried to add (as suggested here [How do I disable my system from going to sleep?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47311/how-do-i-disable-my-system-from-going-to-sleep)) the following, but didn't succeed:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/acpi-support # and then set SUSPEND_METHODS="none"
sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the screen failure, because the pc thinks the lid has been closed!
To solve this problem, edit this file:

```
 /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Uncomment the line: `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` and replace `suspend` with `ignore` like this: `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`, finally restart your system.

I hope this can help you!