# Dual Monitor does not turn off after delay (HDMI / VGA)

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04, power-management, hdmi, vga

I have one main HDMI monitor and I used to setup Ubuntu to auto turn off screen and then block the system.

Now I have installed a second VGA screen and things got wierd.

When the screens turn off after delay, the second VGA screen immediately turns on. And this event turns the other, the main screen, on also.

It seems that this VGA screen sends some feedback signal when turning off, so Ubuntu takes it as if I was plugging a screen on a idle system and back to work.

I think, but I am not sure, that the workaround is somethig [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773722/ubuntu-16-04-unplug-vga-sleep).

Can anyone please help me?
Tks!

PS: My CPU is a AMD Ryzen 3400g on a Asus Prime A320M-K, no video card.