# Prevent monitors from going black on lockscreen

Tags: 16.04, gnome, 16.10

Using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 I want my screens to stay on after locking. After locking ( Super + L ) I see the Curtain-Image for about one second before my screens go black. Once I push any key my screens need several seconds before they are showing anything again so I would prefer them to stay active all the time even when station is locked.

I already tried `xset -dpms` and some settings in `gsettings` but nothing worked for me.

How can I disable the timeout so the screens stay active?

**EDIT**: meanwhile updated to Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, still have the same issue

Comment: Did you check with the available options in the power management setting?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47311/how-do-i-disable-my-system-from-going-to-sleep?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee the power management settings in systems settings are... not worth to be mentioned. Screen shutdown time is set to never but that's all regarding to screen settings.

Comment: @MaheshGareja I've had a look at this post but I can't find the setting from the highest rated answer. There is no `gnome-power-manager` within `apps`.  And I did not know how exactly to implement the solution of the accepted answer.  The mentioned line says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`, how do I have to add `acpi=off` and `apm=off` without messing with my grub settings?

Comment: @viper1209: What Mahesh suggested, seems to be a solution. In Gnome, there is gconf-editor (write 'gconf-editor' in terminal), if not, then install it with apt-get. Then rest will be easy.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee I know how it is meaned. I opened gconf-editor but there is no `gnome-power-manager` in `apps`. I looked through the whole tree (not every single value but the folders) to see if something got moved but there is nothing which seems to be what I'm looking for

Comment: Does no one has any more ideas?