# Disabling sleep mode on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, suspend

how can I disable my unit from entering sleep mode?

Using Ubuntu 14.04 Mini-ISO. Don't have a gui.

Comment: Possibly related answer:  https://askubuntu.com/a/130541/231142

Comment: Note that the most upvoted answers on the "this is a duplicate, here's the answer" link are for the 16.04 version may not work on the 14.04 one. I have the 14.04 one and they didn't work there.

Answer (score 1):

From terminal edit the acpi-support file. I have used nano, you can use any other editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/acpi-support
```

Then set `SUSPEND_METHODS="none"`

Save the file.

Then:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out. A colleague of mine spoke about acpi and we noticed we couldn't change the acpi settings in bios. This might work! I'll mark as solved if it works when I've tested it!

Comment: @JonathanÖhrström, did it work for you?