# Latest upgrade of Ubuntu 18.04 leads to automatic sleep and wake servers

Tags: server, upgrade, suspend, restart

My servers behave strange 5 days now. They go to sleep mode after about 10 minutes and on again, and off, and on periodic. Power configuration is Suspend Off. I do not how to fix. Both servers are unstable like that after sudo apt dist-upgrade. Tried to downgrade to kernel 4.15 from 4.16 do not solve the problem.
Please help.

Comment: 18.04 is not released yet. Bugs are to be expected and need to be reported on launchpad. Upgrading a server to a not-released OS is not the best choice to make. You will probably need to re-install, and restore a backup to revert back to 16.04 if you can not fix yourself.

Comment: Very good suggestion about not use Development version for something important. Thank you.

Comment: Same problem here. Desktop version, on Lenovo T430s, with rc4 kernel of 4.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch a bug report, it seems like it bug. however try Unity Tweak Tool it may have some power settings within it. if not disable sleep mode.

[How do I disable my system from going to sleep?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47311/how-do-i-disable-my-system-from-going-to-sleep)

Comment: It is probably Gnome Tweak Tool now a days, since that the default DE for 18.04.

Comment: Please do not provide answers  for a server with software where you need a desktop.

Comment: Thank you so much, Joel. I followed the link you provided. Tried the second guide with "sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target". And the two IoT servers is up and running again. Never sleep after 1 hour. Lovely.