# Disabled Sleep mode failed in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and after update to the latest kernel I can't seem to disable my laptop from going to sleep after a few minutes, even though sleep mode is disabled already. It even goes to sleep when I'm watching a movie, it's annoying.

Here's screenshot of my power setting

[image]

I also follow some instructions from : [How do I disable my system from going to sleep?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47311/how-do-i-disable-my-system-from-going-to-sleep) to execute :

`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`

Still not working, my laptop still goes to sleep mode. I've also tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout '0' 
&& gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout '0'
```

But my laptop still goes to sleep. I also came across suggestion to add `acpi=off` in GRUB setting but then I also read it can lead to many [other effects](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options). Literally a few minutes ago it went to sleep that's why I remember to post it here.Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gnome, you can use dconf-editor. You can install it via apt.

For me, it was a similar setting: /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-type