# Ubuntu Server 20.04 going into suspend every 20 mins

Tags: 20.04, suspend, hibernate

Tonight my server updated with the latest gnome-shell:amd64 3.36.4-lubuntu~20.04.2 update and since applying this update the server has repeatedly gone into a hard drive stasis every 20 minutes (approx). The drives only come alive again by me pressing the server's power button momentarily and after another 20 minutes it does the same thing again. My server is headless and until tonight has never suffered this issue.

Is there a config setting that has been changed by this update and if so which one and how do I resolve it please?

Comment: This https://askubuntu.com/questions/47311/how-do-i-disable-my-system-from-going-to-sleep might help you out.  Look in the `/etc/systemd/system` folder at the `.target` files listed in the top answer and see if they point to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl --since="-25 minutes"`.

Comment: My ODROID XU4 with 20.04 is doing this too.  So far I've had no luck with every funky command line magic to make it stop.  Tempted to just go back to 18 as this is borderline useless as a media server.