Poweroff does not work since upgrade to 24.04
I have upgraded last week to 24.04. Since then my laptop does not power off alright. Everything seems to turn off but when I try to power it back on with the power-on button nothing happens at all. The only way to bring the system back on is to hold the power button for 10sec and after that the power-on works again.
Any ideas?
Thanks
Pawel

see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/858617/1698042

I have the same issue on my laptop.
As part of upgrade to 24.04 (from 22.04) a new kernel is installed.
It looks like the problem is somehow related to this newer kernel (6.8.0-31).
When the laptop is started with older kernel (6.5.0-35) the issue is not observed.

Seems it is not a "laptop issue". In my Desktop, sometimes PoweOff goes ok, sometimes it makes the shutdown but stays on.
